Most efficient way to uniformize names in a pandas data frame using unique id's that correspond to multiple variations of the same name
I'm doing some data analysis on a DataFrame that contains a few columns with unique id's and a few columns with some names, where each unique id corresponds to a name, 'though the same id can correspond to a few variations of the same name, and the order of the names/id's can be changed. For example:



left1_id
right1_id
left2_id
right2_id
left1_name
right1_name
left2_name
right2_name




01
02
03
04
John Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Smith
Ana Smith


01
02
03
04
John A. Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Smith
Ana B. Smith


03
04
01
02
Mike D. Smith
Ana Smith
John Doe
Jane C. Doe


04
03
01
02
Ana B. Smith
Mike D. Smith
John C. Doe
Jane C. Doe



I'm wondering what's the most efficient way to use the unique id to standardise the names. I don't care which version of the name is chosen (could be longer, shorter, first that appears, whatever, as long as it is consistently the same for that ID in every column). An example of an ideal output would be:



left1_id
right1_id
left2_id
right2_id
left1_name
right1_name
left2_name
right2_name




01
02
03
04
John Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Smith
Ana Smith


01
02
03
04
John Doe
Jane Doe
Mike Smith
Ana Smith


03
04
01
02
Mike Smith
Ana Smith
John Doe
Jane Doe


04
03
01
02
Ana Smith
Mike Smith
John Doe
Jane Doe



Since some ids/names don't appear in some columns, I'm thinking that I'd iterate through each column-pair of id/name (left1_id with left1_name, right1_id with right1_name, etc), creating a dictionary with the id as the key and name as a value, then join all the dictionaries together, than map back each combination to each name column. But I think there should be something more efficient.
Thank you in advance,

You can create MultiIndex in columns, create mapping dictionary by DataFrame.stack and zip and map Series created by id columns:
df1 = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)

s1 = df1.xs('id', level=1, axis=1).stack()
s2 = df1.xs('name', level=1, axis=1).stack()

d = dict(zip(s1, s2))
print (d)
{'01': 'John C. Doe', '02': 'Jane C. Doe', '03': 'Mike D. Smith', '04': 'Ana B. Smith'}

df2 = s1.map(d).unstack().rename(lambda x: f'{x}_name', axis=1)
df[df2.columns] = df2
print (df)
  left1_id right1_id left2_id right2_id     left1_name    right1_name  \
0       01        02       03        04    John C. Doe    Jane C. Doe   
1       01        02       03        04    John C. Doe    Jane C. Doe   
2       03        04       01        02  Mike D. Smith   Ana B. Smith   
3       04        03       01        02   Ana B. Smith  Mike D. Smith   

      left2_name   right2_name  
0  Mike D. Smith  Ana B. Smith  
1  Mike D. Smith  Ana B. Smith  
2    John C. Doe   Jane C. Doe  
3    John C. Doe   Jane C. Doe  

Solution with replace like @Kim solution:
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.endswith('name')] 
df[cols] = df.filter(like='id').replace(d).to_numpy()


In your code, generating a mapper with dict+zip seems like a good choice to make your code more concise. +1

@PandaKim - Is replace more faster like map+unstack ? What do you think?

Since already do melt (or stack) to create the mapper, it is expected to be more faster to do a map + pivot (or unstack) rather than replace.

Code
Uses melt to transform the id and name data into a mapper(m).
Replaces the id values with the corresponding name values by m.
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('name')]
tmp = df.filter(like='id')
m = (pd.concat([tmp.melt(), df[cols].melt(value_name='val2')], axis=1)
       .drop_duplicates('value').set_index('value')['val2']
)
df[cols] = tmp.replace(m).values

df:

If you just use pandas, the answer is above, and if you generate m with dict + zip like @jezrael's idea, you can generate it with more concise code.
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('name')]
tmp = df.filter(like='id')
m = dict(zip(tmp.melt()['value'], df[cols].melt()['value']))
df[cols] = tmp.replace(m).values

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'left1_id': ['01', '01', '03', '04'],
    'right1_id': ['02', '02', '04', '03'],
    'left2_id': ['03', '03', '01', '01'],
    'right2_id': ['04', '04', '02', '02'],
    'left1_name': ['John Doe', 'John A. Doe', 'Mike D. Smith', 'Ana B. Smith'],
    'right1_name': ['Jane Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Ana Smith', 'Mike D. Smith'],
    'left2_name': ['Mike Smith', 'Mike Smith', 'John Doe', 'John C. Doe'],
    'right2_name': ['Ana Smith', 'Ana B. Smith', 'Jane C. Doe', 'Jane C. Doe']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

